# Basic use of SUMIF in Numbers app?

Tags: numbers

How does one write a simple SUMIF formula in Apple Numbers app, version 13?

For example…

[image: screenshot of Numbers app spreadsheet of 3 columns]

In this example, I want to write two SUMIF formulas in two cells:

- The sum of numbers in the entire second column title `Amount`, after filtering for those with a value of "in" found in the third column titled `Direction`.
- Ditto, but value of "out`.

Results would be these two numbers:

- `38.38`   [the 1st & 4th items]
- `75.94`   [the 2nd, 3rd, 5th, and 6th items]

I tried this (copy-pasted from Numbers):

```
SUMIF(Direction; "=in"; Amount)
```

Results in error:

> The formula contains a syntax error.

The examples of SUMIF that I have found are more complicated. So I could not decipher this most basic use of SUMIF.

Comment: It looks like the decimal point is represented by a dot on your Mac. If so, you should be using commas instead of semicolons in separating the arguments in a Numbers formula.

Comment: @Alper I just figured that out. Thank you for the comment. Is that a locale-specific thing? With other localization. settings, would a correct formula in Numbers use Semicolon as the argument delimiter?

Comment: Yes, you are right. On my Mac, because the decimal point is set up to be a comma, I separate arguments with semicolons. So, the formula returning an error on yours would work perfectly fine on my Mac! BTW, your SUMIF formula with commas should also work, i.e. when the condition is `=in`.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is close but has two errors:

- Drop the "equals" sign (`=`) from the string in the second argument. So just `"in"`.
- Use Comma as argument separator, not Semicolon. This depends on your localization settings, according to [Comment by Alper](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458902/basic-use-of-sumif-in-numbers-app#comment670863_458902).

Correct formula:

```
SUMIF(Direction,"in",Amount)
```

[image: screenshot of Numbers with successful results]